# Understanding code execution in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Can someone please explain the execution of below code in JavaScript:

```
function modifyData(data) {
    let data2 = data;

    data2.text = "Text Changed!";
}

let data = {
    text: "Original text!"
}

console.log(data.text);
console.log({theData: data});

modifyData(data);

console.log(data.text);
console.log({newData: data});
```

Executing above script logs console values in below order:

1. Original text!
2. theData: {text: "Text Changed!"}
3. Text Changed!
4. newData: {text: "Text Changed!"}

My question is why the second console.log did not log: **theData: {text: "Original text!"}**?

Comment: It has to do with how the browser's debugger works, use `console.log(JSON.stringify({theData: data}))` and you'll get the expected result.

Comment: Thank you @Titus for the suggestion.
For others who may find this question and looking for an answer, please look at the links on top provided by VLAZ and Bergi.